# Can I force Maven to download dependencies via HTTPS?

Tags: maven, https

I am working on my company's server and am trying to circumnavigate many permissions and firewall blockages in order to build a Maven project. My latest issue is that the server is blocking my request to download a dependency over HTTP. However, if I "curl" the page using HTTPS, I am able to bypass the firewall, and thus would like to instruct Maven to use this type of connection to pull dependencies.

Most of the information I've already found on SO is related to creating a secure HTTPS connection to Maven Central itself, not to the URLs of the dependencies. Is there a way to specify this in the settings.xml or pom.xml files?

Comment: Does your compony has a repository manager ? If yes than use this one...

Comment: no this is unfortunately not available

Comment: I strongly recommend to start using one...furthermore which Maven version are you using? Have you configured things in your `settings.xml` file?

Comment: our server admins won't give me access to the global settings.xml, but I've played around with the local one in my home directory's .m2 folder. But I wasn't able to figure out which setting I had to change to solve this problem.

Comment: If you are using a build server this build server should handle this on it's own.....Which Maven version do you use?

Comment: We are using maven 3.5.3